# How do I get a dynamic json value by string?

Tags: c#, json, string, winforms, dynamic

I am doing a method for getting a json value.
My problem is, that if I try to implement the arguments of the method to the dynamic json value, it doesn't work.
If I just write the "path" for the value, it does work.
In this code the `string value= json.myDirectory.myJson;` is my "path" and its also working.

```
        public static Int32 GetJson(string Directory, string json)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var responseString = client.GetStringAsync("LinkToTheWebsite").Result.ToString();
                dynamic json = JObject.Parse(responseString);
                string value= json.myDirectory.myJson; <- this is working but if i try this, its not:
 string value= json.Directory.json
                MessageBox.Show(value);
            }
            return 1;
        }
```

Error: `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The runtime binding cannot be executed for a NULL reference.`
But if I call the method with `GetJson("myDirectory", "myJson");` It will cause the error I mentioned above, in this line `string value= json.Directory.json`.

Comment: Share an example of json data and describe the expected behavior.

Comment: We would need to see the value of `responseString` in various cases. Also, why do you have the argument `string Directory` in the method, if you are not using it - not sure if this causing some confusion for you.

Answer (score -1):

string jsonOffset = json[Directory][json];
the first json is my dynamic value where I parse it, and the second json in the [] is the string.

Comment: This is not how things works. if you want anyone to understand anything you wrote here, plese do not post questions like "aha-query? what?" and answers like "ha-ha-gotcha"